# Regex, get all data between "?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some string with url data

> http://www.abc.xyz?data1?data2?data3?data4?data5

I'm looking for regex or function to save that data in array, object or 4 diffrent strings. In javascript.

Found `/\?(.*?)\?/g` but that doesn't work properly...

Comment: Add complete code of how the RegEx is used.

Comment: `window.location.search.split("?").slice(1)` Strange way to use a query string...Most people would use name, value pairs.

Comment: That's a strange looking URL, does your keyboard not have the `&` character ?

Comment: between or after? data5 is not between "?" it will be in the needed output?

Comment: \?([^?]*)(?=\?) if you want to use regex

Answer (score 1):

Use split:

```js
var url = 'http://www.abc.xyz?data1?data2?data3?data4?data5';
var pieces = url.split('?');
// drop the url part
pieces.shift();
// show result
document.write(pieces);
```

However, it's important to note that url query strings are separated by `&`, so you would more likely have:

`var url = 'http://www.abc.xyz?data1=foo&data2=bar&data3=baz&data4=etc&data5=etc';`

You could parse this out, but it's much easier to use `location.search` which will return an array of query string values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regex you can try this:

```
//The regex will not get the fifth data, the question says, and i quote
//´Regex, get all data BETWEEN“?”´ you can remove the lookahead (?=\?) if you want all data
var re = /\?([^?]*)(?=\?)/g; 
var str = 'http://www.abc.xyz?data1?data2?data3?data4?data5';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI2lB8/7)

Comment: `"/\?([^?]*)(?=\?)/g"` - really? Did you test it? There are two issues here. One is critical.

Comment: That is a *regex* demo. And here is a [*code* demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyo15qwn/) showing it does not work => *Uncaught TypeError: `re.exec` is not a function*. Please fix.

Comment: Good, now look at `\?([^?]*)(?=\?)` - what is redundant?

Comment: the lookahead? (thow , he OP says betwen ? so the fith data should´nt be coght), thx a lot for the rectifications, but, why the regex work different in the two sites? exluding (sorry my inglish) the " the same regex in demo capture the 4 data, and in the code demo it only capture data4, the last

Comment: Ok, here is the point where I do not understand the question. If the `?` at the end must be there, then really you need the lookahead. If all the parts after the first `?` are needed, then the lookahead should be removed. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyo15qwn/1/) and the [other demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyo15qwn/2/).

Comment: I left the comment in OP question...becouse it seems VERY rare that the fifth data will no be necesary...but..if the questions says literally betwen..betwen it is... but i should put the note at least. Again, thx for the rectifications :)